# In *.bib with `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, how can I put "early access" before month and "doi" after year?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am using IEEEtran style.
According to [this IEEE Reference Guide webpage](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE_Reference_Guide.pdf), the following format is exactly what I want:

- Basic format:

> J. K. Author, "Name of paper," *Abbrev. Title of Periodical.*, Abbrev. month, year. doi: xxx.

- Example:

> F. Vatta, A. Soranzo, and F. Babich, "More accurate analysis of sum-product decoding of LDPC codes using a Gaussian approximation," *Commun. Lett.*, early access, Dec. 11, 2018. doi: 10.1109/TBME.2011.2158315.

---

The following code is what I typed but not working well. Exactly saying, early access appeared after year, and doi is not shown.

```
@article{vatta2018more,
  title={More accurate analysis of sum-product decoding of {LDPC} codes using a {Gaussian} approximation},
  author={F. Vatta and A. Soranzo and F. Babich},
  journal={Commun. Lett.},
  month=dec,
  year={2018},
  note={early access},
  doi={10.1109/TBME.2011.2158315},
}
```

Can you please let me know how can I make the result like the example?

FYI) My document class is `\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: Irrelevant: I think IEEEtran does not show doi by default. And this journal should actually be `{IEEE} Commun. Lett.` which is used in `IEEEabrv.bib`. So if you use `IEEEabrv.bib` it is `journal=IEEE_J_COML`. It is strange that the official IEEE guidance gives that format but I never omit `IEEE` in my paper.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Yes, I agree with your comment, but that document shows just examples. Journal name is arbitrarily defined, I think. The most important thing is that I want to put doi, but I can't now. Actually, I've many times ever seen papers published in IEEE Transactions on something in which papers are cited with their DOI numbers.

Comment: It indeed seems difficult because there are so few fields supported in `@article`, but it can be *faked* through `month={early access, Dec.},` and `note={doi: 10.1109/TBME.2011.2158315},`.

Comment: Found another problem that this document by the IEEE may not be very rigorous because it adds the date which is not seen on the format.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I got some inspiration from your comment (about the fake method). Thanks.